# How to compare two Vectors and clip the first Vector values by the maximum value in another Vector using Math.NET Numerics

Tags: c#, math.net

I have two arrays

```
double[] a = new double[] {1,2,3,4,5}; 
double[] b = new double[] {2,3,2,3,5};
```

which I convert into two vectors:

```
Vector<double> A = Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(a);
Vector<double> B = Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(b);
```

I would like to compare the values of 'A' against 'B' and return a vector where elements 2 and 3 (0,1,2,3,4) are clipped because they are greater than the equivalent value in 'b' e.g:

```
[1,2,2,3,5]
```

Can anyone explain how to do this without resorting to a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the [`Map2`](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Vector%601.htm#Map2) method can do what you want.  From the documentation:

> `Vector<T> Map2(Func<T, T, T> f, Vector<T> other, Zeros zeros)`
> Applies a function to each value pair of two vectors and returns the results as a new vector.

Note that the third parameter is actually optional and has a default value of [`Zeros.AllowSkip`](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Zeros.htm#AllowSkip).

You can use the method like this:

```
Vector<double> C = A.Map2((x, y) => (x > y ? y : x), B);
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hfWJhI

Comment: Glad I could help!